# How do you leave Windows Remote Desktop Connection with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

Is it possible to exit a Windows Remote Desktop Connection in full-screen mode with a keyboard shortcut?

I'm using Windows 8.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

1. First press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> to activate the connection bar

   **or** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> to switch from full-screen-mode to window mode.
2. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other method you may prefer to switch between open windows.

To learn more from the source I used, visit here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows-8/keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: If I go with `Pause/Break`, then I can get back to the Remote Desktop in the same way. If I go with `Home`, then there is no way to get back to the Remote Desktop with keyboard only.

Comment: @FranklinYu I don't have any issues getting back to the Remote Desktop when using `Home`. I just use `Ctr` + `Alt` to get back to the Remote Desktop and it works.

Comment: @drinovc That's weird. I tried again just now. First I use `Ctrl` `Alt` `Home` to escape the RDP; then I switched to another program at client side (my browser) with `Alt` `Tab`; then I switched back with `Alt` `Tab`; then I hit `Ctrl` `Alt` as you instructed; then I tried switching window within the RDP session with `Alt` `Tab` but it switched to another program in client side, indicating that it didn't get inside the RDP session.

Comment: It'd be nice if my laptop had either of those buttons... `home` and `break`

Answer (score 6):

You can disconnect from a windows 10 session with tsdiscon.exe . I created a taskbar short cut for just this purpose. Not sure if that executable is available in windows 8. (it should be). I found this to be the most expedient way to logoff a remote desktop session when the remote desktop bar is intentionally hidden (it always seemed to be in the way).

PS: The tsdiscon.exe file should be located on the PC you're remoting into (not the one your on).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to quickly move between remote PC and non-remote laptop, then the following method would allow you to quickly switch between the two side.

*Prerequisite*: A working laptop track pad able to detect 4 point touch or more

1. Create a new Desktop (Press `Win` + `Tab`, you will see the *New Desktop* button)
2. Connect your Remote site in full screen using **Desktop 1**
3. Put **4 fingered** into your track pad, and swipe **right**
4. You should be on your **Desktop 2** now, and you can start your non-remote work there
5. Switch back to remote site by Put **4 fingered** into your track pad, and swipe **left**
6. You should now be in **Desktop 1** again

Comment: This is a sneaky way to do it. Thanks for the answer. Is there a similar way using New Desktops to do this on an actual PC (not a laptop so no 4 finger track-pad command)

Comment: Not that I think of. Even with the Virtual touchpad like so: https://www.wpxbox.com/enable-hidden-virtual-touchpad-windows-10-creators-update/ It would be much more difficult to do the swipe. Maybe if we use macro tools like AutoHot key might work. Not sure

Comment: Windows logo key + Ctrl + Right/Left arrow